# Resize my Android application when I call ssoftkeyboard

Tags: android, resize, android-softkeyboard

I have a problem with the softkeyboard in my application. When I press the edit text the soft keyboard appears over the edit text. I read the documentation from Android and I put in AndroidManifest.xml `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">` but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest making the root view a ScrollView?

Comment: I made like you said and it's working. But why adjustResize it's not working? It's weird...

Comment: Honestly Ziziana, I don't know. I came across the problem myself and that's how I resolved it. it may be a work around but I'm glad it has been able to resolve your issue, even if it is a temporary fix. =0)